# pop up buffer menu is slow

Tags: emacs, elisp

When clicking C-mouse-1 in emacs you get a pop up buffer menu to select opened buffers from.
I noticed after switching from emacs 23 to 24 that the menu is slow to open "categories".
For example I have :

```
Fundamentals
Dired by name
C
Others
```

Moving the mouse to one of these categories wont open the list of buffers inside it without moving the mouse a little more.

Meaning, I would move the mouse lets say on Fundamentals, it gets highlighted but doesn't show the second level popup with the list of buffers, I need to move the mouse some more "while still on Fundamentals" to reveal the list.

This was not the behavior in emacs 23 where the second level list opens instantly once you hover the mouse on the category.

Any reason for that? And a possible fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the difference between Lucid menus and Gtk menus.  IOW it's probably not the change in Emacs version but the fact that your Emacs-23 was built with the Lucid toolkit whereas your Emacs-24 is built with the Gtk toolkit.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.
So basically there is nothing I could do that would help with this issue?

Comment: Not sure, but if my diagnostic is right, then you can fix this issue by simply using an Emacs-24 built with the Lucid toolkit.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which toolkit was used to build the emacs I am running?

Comment: Well, you can just look at the Emacs frames ;-)

Or else, you can use `M-x emacs-version RET`.

Comment: Yup...GTK+.
Will see if I can find a different package. Thanks Stefan.